# PHP: count elements with same class

Tags: php, html, class, count

I am creating and filling an HTML table using PHP. 
During this each TR gets a certain class.

Is there a way I can count how many elements have this class so that I can echo the number somewhere on the page on page load ? (Other TRs would have different or no classes.)

**Example TR:**

```
<tr class="myClass"></tr>
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: use javascript/jquery

Comment: There's lots of ways. How are you building the table originally?

Comment: In pure JS: `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jquery:

```
$('.myClass').length
```

Comment: Thanks. Not PHP but that works as well. :) I will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery ([enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/length/))

```
var n = $( "myClass" ).length;
```